# Showing hidden div in ajax success function for displaying a remaining registration form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following is the jquery script for my otp.

```
<Script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#otp_submit').click(function(){
                var otp_insert=$('#otp_insert').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url:'smsverify.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:{otp_insert:otp_insert},
                     /* beforeSend: function(){
                        $('.image_loading').show();
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $('.image_loading').hide();
                    },*/
                    success: function(data){
                        if(data.success==1){
                            $('.hide2show').show();
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.hide2show').offset().top }, 'slow');

                       }
                            else
                            {
                                    $('.result').html(data);
                            }

                    },
                    error: function() { 
                      console.error('Failed to process ajax !');
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </Script><!-- Send Otp To the mobile number using ajax -->
```

This is the script which send data to smsverify.php and now this is my smsverify.php script

```
<?php

session_start();
$otp_password=$_POST['otp_insert'];
echo $otp_password;


if($_SESSION['otpkey']==$otp_password) {
    echo "OTP is granted using session";

} else {
    echo "otp is not granted not session";
}

?>
```

This is php script to validate sms otp which send by user.

actually script works fine , but when it returns the data .it is only showing the echo message. not showing the `.hide2show` class which is contain remaining registration form.

```
<div class="row">
                    <h4 class=""> <Strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Primary Details : </Strong></h4>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label> Your Email - </label>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="email_user" id="email_user" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="form-control">
                         <span id="error" style="display:none;color:red;">Wrong Email Id , Kindly Enter valid E-mail Id</span><i class="fa  fa-file-text-o errspan"></i>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- end of emaiol row--><label></label>
                                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label> Your Mobile Number - </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                       <input type="text" name="mobile_user" id="mobile_user" placeholder="Enter Your Mobile Number ( 10 Numbers Allowed Only)" class="form-control"  required  title=" Wrong Mobile Number , Only 10 Digits Allowed" onkeypress='return isNumberKey(event)'  maxlength="10"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-mobile-phone errspan" ></i> <span id="error_mob" style="display:none;color:red;">Wrong Mobile Number Kindly Enter Valid Number</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="button" name="otp_send" id="otp_send" class="btn btn-info btn-block" Value="Send OTP" disabled="disabled">

                    </div>  
                </div><!-- end of emaiol row--><label></label>  
                    <img src="../assets/img/289.gif" class="image_loading" style="display:none;">
                <div class="row hide4otp" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <label> One Time Password - </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type="text" name="otp_insert" id="otp_insert" placeholder="Enter One Time Password"  class="form-control" maxlength="5" ><span id="error_otp" style="display:none;color:red;">Wrong OTP , Kinldy Enter a Valid OTO Which You Have Received On Your Mobile</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <input type="button" name="otp_submit" id="otp_submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-block" Value="Press Me !!" disabled="disabled">
                    </div>  
                </div><!-- end of emaiol row--><label></label>
                                    <div class="row hide2show">
                                        <h4 class=""> <Strong> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Property Information : </Strong></h4>
                                            <div class="col-md-3">
                            <strong>Property For : </strong>
                      </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                          <select name="proerty_for" id="proerty_for" class="form-control" >
                            <option value="Sale"> For Sale</option>
                                                        <option value="Rent"> For Rent</option>
                          </select>
                                            </div>
                                    </div><!-- end of Property_for--><label></label>

This is html code for your relevnce
```

Comment: Can you post your relevant html as well?

Comment: What does `console.log(data.success);` give you?

Comment: IT is not giving me any error..no error is occuring. script giving me echo message of "otp is granted using session"  , but i want to show hidden class i.e .hide2show if and only if there is a meassage of  "otp is granted using session" message.

Comment: It shouldn't give you an error, it should give you a value. You have `if(data.success==1){` so if that value isn't `1` then you will see the response from the PHP script. Check that value and see what it actually is.

Comment: Per your update, you aren't currently checking the actual response form the PHP script, just that it was successful.

Comment: i checked it. i got the problem i.e it is only checking the condition and retrieve the data via ajax to .result class. can you please give me guide to finish my task. i will be very help full to you.

Comment: To me the solution would be `if(data.trim() == 'OTP is granted using session') {`.

Comment: @AustinSchmidt i have enclose and update with html code.

Comment: @chris85 i tried this out. but is going into else part. not working , please let me know another method.

Comment: @chris85 its working now. thanks for giving the hint of trim function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code ,it may work for you

```
<?php

session_start();
$otp_password=$_POST['otp_insert'];

if($_SESSION['otpkey']==$otp_password) {
   echo "1";
} else {
  echo "0";
}

?>
```

and in your ajax response check with

```
if(data=='1'){
   // your code
}
```

Comment: You need to remove the `echo $otp_password;` as that will be passing the password back to the AJAX `success` function and confusing everything

Answer (score 3):

`data.success` is accessing the the success property of the object `data` . However, you are not returning an object from your PHP. Modify your PHP to return an object in JSON.

```
<?php

session_start();
$otp_password=$_POST['otp_insert'];
$response = array();


if($_SESSION['otpkey']==$otp_password) {
    $response['success'] = 1;
    $response['message'] = "OTP is granted using session";
} else {
    $response['success'] = 0;
    $response['message'] = "OTP is not granted using session";
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(data){
                        var result = $.trim(data);
                        if(result=="OTP is granted using session") {
                            $('.hide2show').show();
                            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('.hide2show').offset().top }, 'slow');


                       }
                            else
                            {
                                    $('.hide2show').hide();
                                    $('#error_otp_valid').show();
                                    console.log('Wrong OTP , Please try again Later');

                            }

                    },
                    error: function() { 
                      console.log('Failed to process ajax !');
                    }

This is my Ajax success part. thanks everyone . it helps me alot. i also learn a new things of console and trim function in jquery.
```